# Iteration in java 8 returning last value in list

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Clearly I am not good with Java 8. Can someone tell me why my set is not keeping all my values during iteration? If I put a breakpoint, the code iterates but returns last value only.

```
Set<Group> groups = new Hashset<>();
Group group = new Group();
List my = model.getValues();

list.stream().forEach(gr -> {
            group.setName(gr.getDescription());
            group.setDescription(gr.getDescription());

           groups.add(group); 
});

System.Out.Println(groups);
```

Comment: `list.stream().map(gr->{Group group = new Group(); group.setName(gr.getDescription());
            group.setDescription(gr.getDescription());return group;}).collect(toSet());`

Comment: There are too many problems in this code to even compile. If you have some specific problem with code which works (even in the way you don't want to) then please include in your question only code which actually lets us reproduce that problem, don't add problems which are unrelated to what you want to ask about (it is a waste of your time and our effort if we focus on problems unrelated to real issue).

Answer (score 4):

Because you're creating it outside of lambda expression. You need to create a fresh instance in every iteration, this should work:

```
Set<Group> groups = new Hashset<>();
List my = model.getValues();

list.stream().forEach(gr -> {
           Group group = new Group();
           group.setName(gr.getDescription());
           group.setDescription(gr.getDescription());

           groups.add(group); 
});
```

Or even cleaner using `map`:

```
Set<Group> groups = list.stream()
    .map(gr -> new Group(gr.getDescription(), gr.getDescription())))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Provided there is a proper, two-parameter constructor.

Comment: Your first solution does not work with a set. You will get the first value only. I had to change it to list then it worked. Thanks

Comment: @Etch If the first doesn't work, then the second solution posted here shouldn't work either. They both intend to perform a similar operation with just different syntax. Besides that, using raw type `List` should be avoided and setting the same value for both `name` and `description` attributes seem to be another problem with the code while the `equals` implementation for `Group` is abstract in the question.